# How to Run Vertx with Java 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, vert.x, intellij-13

I've downloaded and have Vertx running, but when I edited one of the examples to start using Java 8 features (lambdas) I kept getting compiler errors. In Intellij, everything compiles just fine and I have IntelliJ pointing to my Java 8 JDK, but when I run Vertx from the command line, the compilation errors occur:

```
> vertx run FanoutServer.java
C:\Users\i50640\Documents\Intellij Projects\EchoServer\src\main\java\echoserver\FanoutServer.java:33: error: illegal start of expression
        vertx.createNetServer().connectHandler(socket -> {
                                                       ^
C:\Users\i50640\Documents\Intellij Projects\EchoServer\src\main\java\echoserver\FanoutServer.java:33: error: illegal start of expression
        vertx.createNetServer().connectHandler(socket -> {
                                                         ^
C:\Users\i50640\Documents\Intellij Projects\EchoServer\src\main\java\echoserver\FanoutServer.java:33: error: ';' expected
        vertx.createNetServer().connectHandler(socket -> {
                                                          ^
C:\Users\i50640\Documents\Intellij Projects\EchoServer\src\main\java\echoserver\FanoutServer.java:34: error: illegal start of expression
            connections.add(socket.writeHandlerID());
Failed in deploying verticle
java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:108)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:51)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$21.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1723)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:175)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:370)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed!
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:105)
    ... 7 more

Failed in deploying verticle
java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:108)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:51)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$21.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1723)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:175)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:370)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed!
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:105)
    ... 7 more
```

And here is the FanoutServer.java file:

```
public class FanoutServer extends Verticle {

    public void start()  {
        final Set<String> connections = vertx.sharedData().getSet("conns");

        vertx.createNetServer().connectHandler(socket -> {
            connections.add(socket.writeHandlerID());
            socket.dataHandler(buffer -> {
                for (String actorID : connections) {
                    vertx.eventBus().publish(actorID, buffer);
                }
            });
            socket.closeHandler(new VoidHandler() {
                public void handle() {
                    connections.remove(socket.writeHandlerID());
                }
            });
        }).listen(6748);
    }
}
```

Do I need to download the Vertx source code and compile it in Java 8 before being able to use Java 8 features? If not, what do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is found here at the google group for Vertx:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/pG7mIo3-03o

In short, my JAVA_HOME variable on my windows machine was pointed to JDK 1.7 instead of 1.8.

Answer (score 3):

Check your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and make sure it also points to the right `jdk`.